# changing js function after page callback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to know if it possible to change js function content and execute it with button.I do the change in code behind with asp.net in a callback and not a postback.

Comment: Possible to change: No. Possible to override the whole function: Yes.

Comment: thnaks for your replay Teemu.So do you know how to do this?

Comment: You specifically asked if it's possible. Please ask what you want to know, in the OP ...

Comment: Please show some code on you like to do it... there are many ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can do,you can loose one function definition and replace it with another.

```
 var a = function() { return 1; }
 alert(a()) // 1

a = function() { return 2; }
alert(a()) // 2
```

Comment: Now if you want to know how to do it in your case, you may need to send some code !

Comment: thanks  psylogic I am trying your code to see if it will work in my case

Comment: finally I learned that changind a js function is possible and overriding it is possible also.my problem was not resolved but this code was helpfull.Thanks for all who tryed to help me.May be my question was not clear because I have not explained the hole situation clearely .